# Adding Medium Editor to Angular Project

Tags: angular, npm, installation, editor

Ok, so I'm trying to integrate a medium editor into my angular project but it doesn't seem to work, here's my code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import MediumEditor from 'medium-editor';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<div #media></div>`,
})

export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('media') media: ElementRef;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const edit = this.media.nativeElement;
    const editor = new MediumEditor(edit);
  }
}
```

I added the following css to my styles.css file

```
@import url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/medium-editor@latest/dist/css/medium-editor.min.css');
@import url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/medium-editor@latest/dist/css/themes/default.css');
```

I'm not sure what seems to be the problem, but the medium editor doesn't seem to be coming up at all.

Comment: Don't see any issues see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-buyux6

Answer (score 0):

i know its pretty late for this answer, but hope this helps. I happen to work very recently on medium-editor in angular, I followed this article [Integrate Medium Editor](https://blog.smartcodehub.com/integrate-medium-editor-in-angular-8/), my component goes like this:

```html
import { Component, OnInit, AfterContentInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
declare var MediumEditor:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.css']
})
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
  editor:any;
  
  @ViewChild('editable', { static: true })
  editable!: ElementRef;

   BUTTONS = [               'bold','italic','underline','subscript','superscript','anchor','quote','pre','orderedlist','unorderedlist','indent',
    'justifyLeft','justifyCenter','justifyRight','justifyFull','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6']

constructor() { }

ngAfterContentInit(): void {
  this.editor = new MediumEditor(this.editable.nativeElement, {
    paste: {
      /* This example includes the default options for paste,
         if nothing is passed this is what it used */
      forcePlainText: false,
      cleanPastedHTML: true,
      cleanReplacements: [],
      cleanAttrs: ['class', 'style', 'dir','name'],
      cleanTags: ['meta'],
      unwrapTags: []
    },
    toolbar: {
      /* These are the default options for the toolbar,
          if nothing is passed this is what is used */
      allowMultiParagraphSelection: true,
      buttons: this.BUTTONS,
      diffLeft: 0,
      diffTop: -10,
      firstButtonClass: 'medium-editor-button-first',
      lastButtonClass: 'medium-editor-button-last',
      // relativeContainer: null,
      standardizeSelectionStart: false,
      static: false,
      /* options which only apply when static is true */
      align: 'center',
      sticky: false,
      updateOnEmptySelection: false
    }
  });
}

ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

In the above mentioned post, they used `AfterViewInit` but I had to replace it with `AfterContentInit` to remove some nasty errors in my console.

and my template code goes like this:

```html
<div class="container mt-3 ">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div #editable class='col-md-6' style="min-height: 85vh"></div>
    <div *ngIf="editor" class="col-md-6 shadow" [innerHTML]="editor.elements[0].innerHTML"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and voila !!!

[image: Medium Editor in Angular]